# Code Composer for Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, compiling, ide, texas-instruments

From the Texas Instruments' website, I can see that there are compile toolchains for Linux-based hosts, but they do not support the C67x family of DSP. Is that correct?

If not where can I found Linux-based Code Composer tools for this family particularly?